# Maintain aspect ratio of image when resizing height of window in both safari and chrome

Tags: reactjs, css, google-chrome, safari

I have the following html & css code that is laying out some cards in a particular manner. I want the card to always maintain their aspect ratio when both the width or height of the window is changed.

I have been developing in chrome and the page has been fine however i just tested in safari and when changing the height it does not maintain the aspect ratio.

I do not know which of the commands is not supported by safari.

https://github.com/AG-Labs/pokerSite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the following websites to find out what is causing the issue:

https://caniuse.com
https://autoprefixer.github.io

I also vaguely remember that vw is not always interpreted the same way but I’m not sure. Would it be an option to change them to the proper percentages? I personally stopped using vw and vh in most situation due to small issues